# Same commit hash, different directory trees between Git on Windows and Git on Linux

Tags: git

I have a GIT repository on a Linux machine where the HEAD commit's SHA1 is let's say `12345abcde`. This repository has several subfolders:

```
  ./
  |-foo
  |  |-bar2
  |-baz
```

When I clone this repository onto a Windows machine, I get the same history, but a different directory structure:

```
  ./
  |-foo
  |  |-bar1
  |  |-bar2
  |-baz
```

The SHA1 of the HEAD commit is the same value: `12345abcde`.

How is this possible? I was under the understanding that if the directory structure is different, the commit hash should be different.

`bar1` used to exist at one point in history and it got deleted and renamed to `bar2`. Therefore, the directory structure on the Linux machine is correct.

Has anyone else seen this? Does anyone know why this can occur?
I have gone back through history and compared the commit hashes of every single commit on the Windows and Linux machines. They match.

How is this possible?

EDIT:

```
Version on Windows (MSYSGit) : 1.8.5.2
Version on Linux (Ubuntu 12.04): 1.7.9.5
```

EDIT2:

```
After updating the version on Linux to 2.0.0, re-creating the repository 
and doing a clone to Windows, the directory trees and SHA1 hashes are consistent.
However, the SHA1 of HEAD on both Linux and Windows is now different - let's say
`67890defgh`
```

If somebody has any insight into why this happens, I'd be happy to accept the answer. The fundamental question here is how can different directory structures be created from the same list of commits with the same hashes?

Comment: They are different, but how would that affect the commit SHAs?

Comment: Was this a fresh clone on the Windows machine?  Is it possible that the file bar1 isn't tracked in the repo?

Comment: @JakeGould: yes, bar1 has content in it. Funnily enough, I'm running 1.7 too on Ubuntu. 
WallyAltman: Yes, this was a fresh clone. Just to check I created a bare clone on the Linux machine and fresh cloned that too to the Windows machine. Same result.

Comment: I should also note that the clone was done over SSH, if it matters.

Comment: Is/was there a Foo/bar1/file, or FOO/bar1, perhaps, on the Linux box?  On Windows with case-folding it will wind up in the lowercase version.

Comment: does one machine have a global `gitignore` that is ignoring `bar1`?

Comment: @torek: At a past point in history yes. But not at HEAD.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: No. Both machines do not have global git ignores set. Only per repo.

Comment: Is `bar1` a submodule? (`git ls-files -s|grep ^16`, as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/23976971/6309)

Comment: No it's not. Just a regular sub folder.